# SignalR + AngularJS 1.x + Redux

Tags: angularjs, signalr, redux

I'm trying to figure out if I can combine the following technologies:

- SignalR (SignalR 2 and MVC 5)
- AngularJS 1.x (Typescript preferably)
- Redux (ng-redux)

Say for creating a simple chat application like this one: [react-redux-socketio-chat](https://github.com/raineroviir/react-redux-socketio-chat) but with angular and SignalR :)

And if so, could someone give a quick example on how to archieve this (client side)

Comment: Most likely you can. But for sure this is not a good question for our Q&A system. What libraries to use is heavily opinion-based in we generally do not ive example code, but help with _specific_ problems.